# Probability problem related to gambler's ruin

Tags: probability

My question is similar to one asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329124/related-to-binomial-distribution), but mine is more generic. Also answers there are too vague.

Game consists of the same and independent rounds, where gambler wins with probability $p$. When gambler wins, he/she gains 1 dollar, when looses - pays 1 dollar. If gambler's bankroll  reached $N$, game ends.
Task is to find the chance, that gambler will go broke before he/she earns $N$, given that bankroll at the start was $K$.

I calculated expected value and sd: $E(X)=2p-1$ $\sigma = \sqrt{2-p+2p^2}$.
So it's possible to find expected value after $m$ rounds, than use Chebyshev's inequality or normal distribution, to assess chance of deviating more... but I believe it's not a way to go, since we can't specify $m$.

Same problem with using binomial formula.
For our task, we could find infinite amount of value pairs: [number of trials, expected number of successes].
Maybe it's possible to express it as infinite sum of different binomials, but I fail to formulate it.

Would appreciate a bit of help here, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One nice approach is to let $p_n$ be the probability that the gambler will end up broke before earning $N$ if the gambler starts with $n$ dollars.  Then, pretty clearly, $p_n = p \cdot p_{n+1} + ( 1 - p )\cdot p_{n-1}$.  We also have $p_0=1$ and $p_N=0$.  Should be pretty easy to solve from here, in a number of different ways.

Comment: You provided the bright idea here, thanks. Thought, these equations require simplification to be considered as proper answer. I tried to deal with it on my own, tried to derive formula of series. But there are to much of recursion there.
Would you provide some hints about one of these 'different ways'?